# Save Variable Value as Percentage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a variable value a percentage, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is what I have:

```js
var x = 50;
var y = 10;

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = y/x;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Although, it shows up as 0.2, and not 20%. Is there a way to fix this, or work around it?

Comment: i think not divide multiply by 100

Comment: Your math is correct but this provides a mathematical percentage: a decimal. To get the percentage, multiple the decimal (0.2 in this case) by 100.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var x = 50;
var y = 10;

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = y/x*100 + "%";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be,

```
Math.floor((y / x) * 100 + "%";
```

**Here is a working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/pwnt08qj/

Hope this helps!

Comment: *"Although, it shows up as 0.2, and not 20%"* - They wanted the `%` character in there also.

Answer (score 0):

10/50 = 0.2 - or what do you expect? That's simple math. If you want percent values, then multiply by 100 and round (if desired)

```
var x = 50;
var y = 10;

function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = Math.round(y/x * 100);
}
```

Comment: *"Although, it shows up as 0.2, and not 20%"* - They wanted the `%` character in there also.

Comment: Then they can add the % character.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the results of division with 100 so it will return percentage value then concatenate "%"

- If x=50 y=10
- results=10/50=0.2
- percentage = results *100

```js
 function displayPercentage() {
var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = Math.round((x / y) * 100) + "%";
        }
```

```html
<lable>x:</lable><input type="number" id="x">
<lable>y:</lable><input type="number" id="y">
<button onclick="displayPercentage()">Click Me!</button>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the result with 100 and concatenate '%'.
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = y/x*100 + "%";

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to save value into percentage

```js
function unitCount () {
var userUnit = document.getElementById("eUnit").value;
    var _50 = 0.50;
    var _100 = 0.70;
    var _200 = 1.20;
    var _250 = 1.50;
    // var addCharge = 20%;
    var first50 = 50;
    var first100 = 100;
    var first200 = 200;
    var first250 = 250;
    if (userUnit <= first50) {
        var total = userUnit * _50;
        total = Math.round(total * 20);
        var _total = total/100;
    console.log(_total+"%");
    }
}
```

```html
<h6>03 - Electricity unit charge</h6>
  <label for="second">&rarr; Unit Input:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="eUnit" placeholder="Enter Electricity Units"><br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="unitCount()">Check Unit Cost</button>
  <p id="resultUnit"></p>
```